# Perl Term::ReadLine::Gnu Signal Handling Difficulties

Tags: perl, readline, signal-handling

I'm using Term::ReadLine::Gnu and have run into a problem with signal handling. Given the script below and a TERM signal sent to the script, the handler for the TERM signal is not triggered until *after* the enter key is pressed. Using Term::ReadLine:Perl this does not occur.

I've read that Term::ReadLine::Gnu has its own internal signal handlers, but frankly I'm at a loss as to how to work with them.

I've reviewed http://search.cpan.org/~hayashi/Term-ReadLine-Gnu-1.20/Gnu.pm#Term::ReadLine::Gnu_Variables tried setting the rl_catch_signals variable to 0, but that didn't help. Ideally, I'd like to work with the Gnu signal handlers, but I'll settle for disabling them too.

To be absolutely specific, I need the TERM handler to trigger after the signal is received instead of waiting for the enter key to be pressed.

Any help or advice is certainly appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::ReadLine;

$SIG{TERM} = sub { print "I got a TERM\n"; exit; };

my $term = Term::ReadLine->new('Term1');
$term->ornaments(0);
my $prompt = 'cmd> ';
while ( defined (my $cmd = $term->readline($prompt)) ) {
    $term->addhistory($cmd) if $cmd !~ /\S||\n/;
    chomp($cmd);
    if ($cmd =~ /^help$/) {
        print "Help Menu\n";
    }
    else {
        print "Nothing\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if this is a buffering issue. Try the solution from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7603502/1791055

Comment: what is `/\S||\n/` supposed to do? :-)  (Not related to your actual question, I just noticed it.)  Note that because there is nothing between your two pipes, the regex will match anything, so !~ will always be false.

Comment: ysth helped me answer this question in another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332908/termreadline-i-need-to-hit-the-up-arrow-twice-to-retrieve-history
Turns out it's completely superfluous as T:R:G does addhistory by default. I'll be removing it.

Comment: titanofold - Thanks for the link. Certainly interesting (and I'll give it a try), but I'm not sure if that would work out for this issue. I think this is more about working with T:R:G's internal signal handling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to perl's default paranoid handling of signals - behind the scenes, perl blocks SIGTERM before starting the `readline` call and restores it when it's finished.  See [Deferred Signals in perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Deferred-Signals-%28Safe-Signals%29) for the details.

`Term::ReadLine::Perl` uses perl's IO, which knows about these issues and deals with them, so you don't see this bug with it.  `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` uses the C library, which doesn't, so you do.

You can work around this with one of two methods:

1. set the environment variable PERL_SIGNALS to `unsafe` before running the script, as in:

   ```
   bash$ PERL_SIGNALS=unsafe perl readline-test.pl
   ```

   Note, `BEGIN { $ENV{PERL_SIGNALS} = "unsafe"; }` isn't enough, it needs to be set before perl itself starts.
2. Use `POSIX` signal functions:

   ```
   #~ $SIG{TERM} = sub { print "I got a TERM\n"; exit; };
   use POSIX;
   sigaction SIGTERM, new POSIX::SigAction sub { print "I got a TERM\n"; exit; };
   ```

   Both the above seem to work in Linux; can't speak for Windows or other unices.  Also, both of the above come with risks - see perlipc for the details.